# Creating XML attribute Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Can anyone help me on writing this line on xml file?

```
<userfield id="sociedad" datatype="string">SS</userfield>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
Debtor.Attributes['datatype'] := 'string';
Debtor.Attributes['userfield id'] := 'sociedad';
```

But when I execute the program I have an error on attribute 'userfield id'.

Comment: Please don't write "I have an error". Please reproduce the error verbatim. Also, please do try to supply an SSCCE. You should be able to supply a 20 line SSCCE for this problem. If you do that you are certain to get excellent answers that solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You did it properly in the first line, without using `userfield` (which is the tag name):

```
Debtor.Attributes['datatype'] := 'string';
```

You should do it the same in the second - set the `id` attribute:

```
Debtor.Attributes['id'] := 'sociedad';
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what that means. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`userfield` is the tag. The attribute is `id`. So, your code should read:

```
Debtor.Attributes['id'] := 'sociedad';
```